# Upload data to table without waiting for streaming buffer to flush

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I have a Go program which downloads data from a table (T1), formats it, and uploads it to a new temporary table (T2). Once the data has been uploaded (30s or so), the data should be copied to a third table (T3).

After uploading the formatted data to T2, querying the table returns results ok. However, when copying the table - the job completes almost instantly and the destination table (T3) is empty.

I'm copying the table as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#bigquery-copy-table-go) - but the result is the same when performing the action in the UI.

In the table metadata section it shows as 0B, 0 rows but there are about 100k rows and 18mb of data in there - or at least that's what comes back from a query.

**Edit** I did not spot that this data was still stuck in the streaming buffer - see my answer.

Comment: Did you create T2 using the streaming API?

Comment: Can you please share T2 Details page from the UI and tell us what you see when you Preview the table

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I've added some detail - I don't think I'm using the streaming API.

Comment: @TamirKlein I've added a screenshot of the details showing 0 bytes but also that the data might still be in the streaming buffer?

I created a table last night and it had the correct values when I looked this morning. Might the issue be that it takes a long time for the streaming buffer to process?

Comment: 1. You can try and query your streaming buffer using this SELECT * from `myProject.myDataSet.t2` where _PARTITIONTIME is NULL 2. The code you added show how you create your table and not how you insert which will tell if you are using streaming buffer

Comment: @TamirKlein, thanks for your replies. I've added the code I'm using to upload the data.

I've tried the partition time query but get the following error `Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME; Did you mean _PARTITION_NAME? ` (_PARTITION_NAME seems to validate but fails to run with a similar error `Unrecognized name: _PARTITION_NAME at [1:71] `)

Comment: Can you add a partition field to T2 table? this will resolve the error `Unrecognized name:` and will enable you to query your streaming buffer

Comment: @TamirKlein I changed the T2 table to a partitioned table and now have the `_PARTITIONTIME` field.

I can upload the data in the same way but the table is empty (I get no results when querying the table, the table size is 0b, there are no longer any streaming stats shown).

I'll wait and see if the data shows up after some delay. How might I work out how long this takes?

Comment: I've managed to get this working as a load job instead. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the streaming buffer issue.

Answer (score 0):

The comments on my question lead me to see that the issue was the streaming buffer. This was taking a long time to flush - it's not possible to flush manually.

I ended up reading this issue and comment on GitHub [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/507#issuecomment-370076232). This suggested using a Load job instead.

After some research, I realised it was possible to read from an `io.Reader` as well as a Google Cloud Storage Reference by configuring the Loader's `ReaderSource`.

My **original** implementation that used the streaming buffer looked like this:

```
var vss []*bigquery.ValuesSaver
// for each row:
vss = append(vss, &bigquery.ValuesSaver{
    Schema:   schema,
    InsertID: fmt.Sprintf(index of loop),
    Row: []bigquery.Value{
        "data"
    },
})

err := uploader.Put(ctx, vss)
if err != nil {
    if pmErr, ok := err.(bigquery.PutMultiError); ok {
        for _, rowInsertionError := range pmErr {
            log.Println(rowInsertionError.Errors)
        }
    }

    return fmt.Errorf("failed to insert data: %v", err)
}
```

I was able to change this to a load job with code that looked like this:

```
var lines []string
for _, v := range rows {
    json, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed generate json %v, %+v", err, v)
    }
    lines = append(lines, string(json))
}

dataString := strings.Join(lines, "\n")

rs := bigquery.NewReaderSource(strings.NewReader(dataString))
rs.FileConfig.SourceFormat = bigquery.JSON
rs.FileConfig.Schema = schema
loader := dataset.Table(t2Name).LoaderFrom(rs)
loader.CreateDisposition = bigquery.CreateIfNeeded
loader.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteTruncate
job, err := loader.Run(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to start load job %v", err)
}
_, err := job.Wait(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("load job failed %v", err)
}
```

Now the data is available in the table 'immediately' - I no longer need to wait for the streaming buffer.

Comment: Great happy to see we managed to get you in the right direction although I still wonder why bq streaming buffer didn't worked.